# stylelint with LESS configuration issue

Tags: less, eslint, prettier, stylelint

**I have next stylelint configuration:**

```
{
  "extends": [
    "stylelint-config-recommended",
    "stylelint-config-recommended-less",
    "stylelint-config-rational-order",
    "stylelint-prettier/recommended"
  ],
  "plugins": ["stylelint-order", "stylelint-less"]
}
```

**In my app.less:**
[image: app.less]

[image: stylelint issue]